# How to set no add-ons mode in SWT Browser(IE)?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, swt, add-on

I want to disable all add-ons in a SWT Browser by using the `SWT.NONE` flag for creating the browser.
In IE I can use the `-extoff` argument to start it in no add-ons mode. Could you give me a way?

Answer (score 0):

The SWT Browser does not have a means to control whether the actual web browser should use extensions or not.